# checking checkbox with selenium ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: selenium

I wanna log to this page automatically an website
but I cant check the checkbox with selenium with this code

```
driver.find_element_by_name('login[terms]').click()
```

and the checkbox html code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="login[terms]" value="1" id="cbx1">
```

and I recieve:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code I recommend two options

- Verify using find by **id** instead by **class name** and check if it works or not with the following code

  `driver.find_element_by_id('cbx1').click()`
- Your code is correct but is recommended to implement an explicit wait to verify and confirm that your element is interactable at the point that you want to use it so that you give a chance to the page to load the element correctly, you can achieve this with the following code

  `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeOut);`

  `WebElement chkBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id( "cbx1")));`

  `chkBox.click();`